# What tools are available to collect statistics on user behavioral patterns?

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, statistics

I have an application with a relatively large user base. I would like to collect statistics on user behavior, analyze patterns etc. I expect that statistics to answer questions like:

- How many female users vs. male users clicked button ABC?
- How many 20-30 years old users followed XYZ behavioral pattern?
- What sequence of actions users take when they work with window DEF?

And so on...

In my opinion Google Analytics is not a good choice as they focus on traffic patterns, rather than application logic.

Are there tracking tools collecting statistics on users and then helping to analyze the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't heard of a tool that gives you demographic information as you specified. And I'm not sure that's possible. The only think you can do is track specific users by using [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/) or Universal Analytics logging in from different devices (PC, mobile, smartwatch), With the normal analytics if a user logs in with a different device it will be displayed as a separate session. However, to be able to use this kind of analytics you need to support user registration.

Comment: Thanks. I have all data on user demographic etc., I just need a tool which would be capable of collecting and slicing and dicing this info. I'll check Mixpanel. What is Universal Analytics?

Comment: Its the same as Mixpanel, but from Google. Basically its Google analytics but with the option to track logins of individual users, see if they are logging in with different devices. The normal analytics cannot track if one user has logged in with different device.